# Is it bad if one of my letters of recommendation talks about research when I am applying for a M.Eng. and not a M.S.?

Tags: phd, masters, application, recommendation-letter, application-cover-letter

Will the committee reviewing the application think: wow he didn't even tell his professor he is going for a non-thesis degree? I ask because I told one of my professors I was going for a masters and did not specify it was an M.Eng. He is likely going to write I could (since I've never done research with him) be a great researcher because of strong work ethic yada yada. He does a lot of research himself and that's why I expect this.

Will This look bad?

Comment: A master's in engineering here would absolutely require research. Why do you think mentioning the potential for you to do this well, would make your application weaker and/or why do you not think your MEng will involve research?

Comment: @nij because at least here in the US, a masters of engineering vs. a master's of science is that there is no thesis for the M.Eng. required and generally don't do research

Comment: ...usually.  MIT's [EECS MEng degree](http://www.eecs.mit.edu/academics-admissions/undergraduate-programs/6-p-meng-program) requires a thesis.

Comment: @JeffE The MIT MEng degree (in most fields, including EECS) is not a graduate degree in normal sense.  It's a five-year undergraduate degree that culminates in a masters thesis.